# How to insert images as pictures in excel using the URL of the picture

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

I am trying to get a full picture to upload onto a worksheet from its url. I have created a form where there is a file upload and I would like for it to show the image rather than a url. Is there a way to do this using office scripts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This sample shows how to add an image to a workbook from a URL: [Add images to a workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/add-image-to-workbook#sample-code-add-an-image-from-a-url-to-a-workbook).

Essentially, you need to use `fetch` to get the image information, convert it to a base64-encoded string, then use [Worksheet.addImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.worksheet?view=office-scripts#addImage_base64ImageString_) to create an Excel shape storing the image.

Since you're using a form, you could create a Power Automate flow that runs the script whenever a [new response is recorded](https://flow.microsoft.com/connectors/shared_microsoftforms/microsoft-forms/). That might be out of scope from your original question, but it's something to consider as a next step.

Comment: Do you know if this script only works with png file types or if you can use .jpg

Comment: The `addImage` API works with .jpg files too.